# Should each React component be responsible for making the API calls for the data it requires?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm building out a ReactJS app that will have its content provided via a RESTful API.

1.) Should I have a single API call when the app mounts that indicates which components should load as well as provide all content (top links list, sidebar content, page content, etc..) or should the top links component make an API request for the data it needs, and each other component make API calls for the data it needs?

2.) I understand that React is the presentation layer, so when the server needs to hide/show components content based on user authentication etc. how should  the react app be "told" what to display/hide.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specifics of the application in question. But as a general answer to the question in the title - no, not in particular.

Usually components will be divided into to types - container components, which handle the logic and delegate the rendering part to other components, and the presentational components, which often are stateless, functional components - they will receive props from the parent and just render a piece of UI. So, the won't call any API-s in their own.

Comment: I can expand further on this questions, if you need more clarification.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and thank you very much for providing feedback. Can you expand on how the server might instruct react on which components to load and not load? Maybe I am still too caught up on the presentational components concept and assuming that the container components not assuming anything about which components should load on page x or y.